# Convergence of $U_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\sigma^2}}\left(\Sigma X_j-\Sigma Y_j\right)$ - central limit theorem

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence

Suppose that $U_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\sigma^2}}\left(\Sigma X_j-\Sigma Y_j\right)$, 
where $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ and $Y_i,Y_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d. sequences of random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and the sequences $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ are independent.

Then, for all real numbers $x$, show that, as $n\to \infty$,

$$\mathbb{P}(U_n\leq x) \to 
\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{(\sqrt(2\pi))} \:e^{-\frac 12{u^2}}\mathrm du $$
**Approach**

I tried to carry out the integration on the right, but this does not integrate nicely. It ends up involving an error function, so I figured this was the wrong was to go.

Should I be looking at convergence in probability to answer this question? Is Chebyshev's inequality relevant here? If so, how and how does that relate to the integral?

Comment: Are the sums in denominator? or outside? what do we know about the first moments of X and Y?

Comment: No the sums aren't in denominator. I've clarified above and also added the mean and variance that we know.

Comment: Update: this is actually to do with central limit theorem, yes?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Use the CLT and continue from there using the fact that linear combination of a normal RV is normal. GL

Comment: Thank you. What are the first steps to take with the $\mathbb{P}(U_n\leq x)$ bit? Presumably this is where to begin?

Comment: I have edited your question to clean up the notation a little, You can revert it back to the previous version if you don't like the changes or if I have changed the meaning of the question.  But, _as stated originally or in the edited question_, **I don't think that what you are trying to prove is true.**  $\Sigma X_n - \Sigma Y_n$ is a zero-mean random variable with variance $2n\sigma^2$ and so $U_n$ cannot _converge_ to anything: its variance is increasing.  The CLT is _not_ applicable to the result you are trying to prove.  You need to fix the definition of $U_n$ to make the CLT work.

Comment: Is it possible that $U_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\left(\Sigma X_j-\Sigma Y_j\right)$?

Comment: @user158565 Most likely your suggestion is correct,  but it is up to the OP to fix  the problem.

Comment: I've corrected the definition of $U_n$.

Comment: That correction makes short work of your question, for now you can recognize $U_n$ as *precisely* the application of the Central Limit Theorem to the iid sequence of random variables $X_n-Y_n.$  All you have to do is compute the variance of $X_n-Y_n.$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} U_n&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n\sigma^2}}\left(\Sigma X_j-\Sigma Y_j\right) \\ & = {\sqrt n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac {X_j - Y_j}{n\sqrt {2\sigma^2}}\right) \\ & = {\sqrt n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac {Z_j}{n}\right) \\
& = {\sqrt n}\bar Z
\end{align}

where $Z_j=\frac {X_j - Y_j}{\sqrt {2\sigma^2}}$. So $E(Z_i) = 0$ and $Var(Z_i) = 1$. Following the central limit theorem (CLT), $U_n$ converges in distribution to standard normal distribution. Then 
$$\mathbb{P}(U_n\leq x) \to 
\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{(\sqrt(2\pi))} \:e^{-\frac 12{u^2}}\mathrm du$$ is obvious.

Comment: Thank you. Why does using the substitution $Z_j=\frac {X_j - Y_j}{\sqrt {2\sigma^2}}$ make sense?

Comment: Because $Z_j$ has the properties that are needed to use CTL and convert to standard normal.